# strategies, for a beginner, to write code (to answer homework question)

Tags: shell-script

There will be a file called `replacewords.txt` 
This will contain data like

```
Apple Orange
Banana Guava
```

etc.

There will be another file called `data.txt`. Word in this file will be replaces, such that, the first column words (from `replacewords.txt`) should be replaced by second column words.

For example if we find `Apple` (in `data.txt`), then replace it by `Orange` and `Banana` by `Guava` etc.

The result should be stored in `Results.txt`

Comment: This is not a do my homework site. However I will give you some help, but not the answer.

Comment: Are you constrained to using a particular language? Which one? What have you tried so far? Do you have any ideas?

Comment: This question may be better served on https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/ (if you like the changes I have made). If so, tell me, and I will ask for it to be moved. The other site is only for asking about teaching and learning techniques, not about helping with the problems directly. However the way I have re-written the question, seems to be a good match.

Answer (score 0):

[I will assume that you are using bash and Gnu utils.]

First break up the question, and tackle one bit at a time.
Before starting ask “what tools have I been learning?”

## Breaking it up

For this example I would break it up like this. (you only need to identify the first one. Get it working, then identify the 2nd. However I have identified some more to help you.)

After each step, test it. Does it work, if not fix it. If it works, then move to next step.

- Read a file (`data.txt`) [cat]
- Read a file and copy/output it to another file (`Result.txt`) [cat and redirection]
- Do a replacement. Don't worry about `replacewords.txt`. Can you just replace Apple with Orange. [sed, and redirection]
- Read in `replacewords.txt`, and use this to control the replacements.
  I have to have a think about what tool can do this. It seems to be a two step process. What option do I have?

  - Write a script that reads `replacewords.txt`, generates a `sed` script, and then executes it. (If I go this way, then first practice by writing a `sed` script that will replace Apples with Oranges and Banana with Guava.)
  - Do it in awk (still a two stage process. Use BEGIN clause to do setup stage.).
  - Do it in python (still a two stage process).
  - Note: Write a dummy stage 1. Hard coding one and then two substitutions. Get it to work, before getting stage 1 to read `replacewords.txt`.